# Two curves for orthogonal trajectory of $y=mx$

Tags: calculus

> Find the orthogonal trajectory of $y=mx$.

We know,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = m$$

For the orthogonal trajectory,
$$-\frac{dx}{dy} = m$$

Integrating both sides we get,
$$y=-\frac{x}{m}$$

But then if I substitute $m$ and then integrate, I get a totally different curve.
$$x^2+y^2=c$$

Are both curves considered to be orthogonal curves to our original equation? I have seen books which give only the second curve as the answer. But is not the first curve orthogonal too? If not, where am I going wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the "orthogonal trajectory" defined?

Comment: A curve which is perpendicular to a given curve at their point of intersection

Comment: Then any straight line with slope $-1/m$ and any circle with center on the line qualifies.

Comment: But my professor said only the second answer is right, not the first one. Am I safe to say he is wrong?

Comment: It very much depends on the exact statement of the problem: if you take $y = mx$ for *ANY* $m$, i.e. the set of straight lines that pass through the origin, then the circles with center at the origin are indeed the set of orthogonal trajectories. But if you are talking about a *single* straight line, then it's what I described before.